# File doesn't created when calling tee command from a python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, shell, tee

I have some program (let's call it `some_program`) that prints to `stdout`, so when I run from my terminal the command below, a new file is been created (`test.bin`) with the content that was generated from the `stdout` of `some_program`:

```
some_program | tee test.bin
```

However, when I try to run `some_program` from a python script (python-3.6) and pipe it into `tee` to create the file `test.bin`, it doesn't work. I do see that `some_program` is running and done it's work, but `test.bin` wasn't created.

Here is my python script:

```
import subprocess
import os

CURR_DIR = os.getcwd()
OUTPUT_FILE = CURR_DIR + '/test.bin'

subprocess.check_output(['some_program', '|', 'tee', '{}'.format(OUTPUT_FILE)])
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

P.S.

I workaround it with this:

```
stdout = subprocess.run(['some_program'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
f = open(OUTPUT_FILE, 'wb')
f.write(stdout)
f.close()
```

But I'm still curious why it doesn't work when piping with `tee`.

Comment: You can't use shell commands with subprocess unless you set `shell=True`

Comment: Indeed, you are passing `|` and `tee` as arguments to `someprogram` here. Apparently it simply ignores any arguments, or you would get an error message about that, like in the duplicate. Perhaps a  better solution is simply to reimplement `tee` in Python, and keep the use of subprocesses to a minimum.

Comment: Ok, now it's clear. Thanks guys